# setting attributes or css of button in code behind in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my aspx code for buttons

```
<div id="navigationButtons">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="button submit" Enabled="true" />   
                <asp:Button ID="btnNext" name="btnNext" Text="NEXT" ToolTip="Next" runat="server" CssClass="button next" TabIndex="0" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="false"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnPrev" Text="PREV" ToolTip="Previous" runat="server" CssClass="button prev" TabIndex="2" OnClick="btnPrev_Click" Enabled="true"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnExit" Text="EXIT" ToolTip="Exit" runat="server" CssClass="button exit" TabIndex="3" OnClick="btnExit_Click" />
        </div>
```

I am unable to change the attributes from code behind so I browsed for the solution and some blogs suggested using following code in the code behind.

```
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlElement)Page.Form.FindControl("btnNext")).Style.Add("visible", "false");
```

I have already tried btnNext.Enabled=false; it is not working.
but when I use it there is null exception error in the code. I don't know how to fix this in the above code behind. Any solution is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with Classic ASP?  Classic ASP and ASP.NET are **NOT** the same thing - more like distant cousins, at best.

Comment: I thought may be someone could know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the `aspx` code which you have provided. Note that I don't have the `cssClass` specified for the buttons.

Now on *Submit Button Click Event*, I wrote the following code.

```
btnNext.Visible = false;
```

And it disables the *Button*. So, some other factor is creating problems for you.

First of all, try this on a new page without adding any `css` files. It will work.
Then try adding that `css` files or classes and check if they are creating problems or not.

Comment: Ok Try like below by removing the `cssClass`...
`<asp:Button ID="btnNext" name="btnNext" Text="NEXT" ToolTip="Next" runat="server" TabIndex="0" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="false"/>`

Comment: You did not get me. I said to remove the `cssClass` and use `<asp:Button ID="btnNext" name="btnNext" Text="NEXT" ToolTip="Next" runat="server" TabIndex="0" OnClick="btnNext_Click" Enabled="false"/>`

Then in code behind, try `btnNext.Visible = false;`

Comment: Can you post the whole page code by editing the Question? As I suggested before, have you tried on a different page with only these buttons and the code `btnNext.Visible = false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the button with it's ID, so you can do something like this:

```
btnNext.Visible = false;
```

Have you already tried this?

Comment: btnNext.Visible = false; is not working thats why I was trying to use the above code

Comment: So instead of Style.Add you should try btnNext.Attributes["style"] = "visibility: hidden";